# How to get the cell value of a gridview in text box when other cell is clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have one gridview with 4 columns namely: "User ID","Description","Display Password","Change Password".

I have put an Image Button in Change Password Column for each cell and below the Gridview there are 3 text boxes.

When I click on Change Password, the User ID of that particular row should be displayed in text box 1.

How to do this in asp.net with C# and back end is MySql DB server?

Answer (score 1):

My preference is to use the `CommandArgument` property and assign a method to the click event directly to the button in the aspx code behind:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnChangePassword" CommandArgument='<%# Eval('UserID') %>' OnClick="MyEventMethod" />
```

Then in the code behind you would have a method to handle it:

```
public void MyEventMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    this.TextBox1.Text = btn.CommandArgument;
}
```

Another method would be to use JavaScript (to avoid the postback) and the onClientClick property. Somewhere above your gridview you'd a method to handle this assignment.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Gets the actual reference to the textbox in javascript
    // using the client id
    function SetTextBoxUserID(userid)
    {
        var textbox1 = document.getElementById('<%= this.TextBox1.ClientID %>');
        textbox1.value = userid;
    }
</script>
```

Then the control would look like:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnChangePassword" OnClientClick='SetTextBoxUserID(<%# "'" + Eval("UserID") + "'" %>)' />
```

Comment: Better to use javascript sample, client side will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Change the "Change Password" column to Hyperlink filed.In the properties of that column in the Data section you can see the DataNavigateUrlFields property. Set it as "User ID". Then in the DataNavigateUrlFormatString property set to the same page as follows

```
~/User.aspx?UserId={0}
```

Then in the page load event write the following code

```
String userId= Request["UserId"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            TextBox1.Text = userId;
```

This might not be the best shoot.But this can be some work around

Comment: Hi Udaya, Thanks for the reply. But I m not getting any option of CellContentClick in .aspx file in which Gridview is define. Which attribute of gridview i have to write?

Comment: I dont Want Hyper Link Udaya. Because I m developing a web portal for a company and they told me to take image there in Change PW column. Please help.